# How should I parallelize the execution of 2 or more json calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to optimize the load time of a webpage, and ran into a conundrum. After doing some JSP refactoring and by reducing the clientlibs that were actually needed by the webpage, I managed to optimize the load time.

[image]

However, I noticed that there are 3 json calls that are originating (see screenshot) and I need to parallelize their execution. As you can see, there are three json calls originating from the page. The first two (in blue box) are say, to load the left div and the top div within the page (to load some topics/groups and notifications, for example). The last call (in the red box) loads the wall posts (facebook type) and this is originating only after the above two calls complete.

I wish to make all three json calls to start (or load the page) at the same time, i.e., in parallel. Can anyone here suggest me how should I go about it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide js code that execute this calls? Seems like third request are called inside second requst 'success' handler. (Or `promise.then` if you are using promises)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need to do is simply make each call together, and if you want to wait until they have all completed before doing something else, store the promises.

Example:

```
$q.all([getThing1().promise, getThing2().promise(), getThing3().promise]).then(function() {
  // Do other stuff once all 3 have finished.
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises#promisifying_xmlhttprequest
function get(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };
    req.send();
  });
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Promise.all([get('https://httpbin.org/get?a=1'), 
               get('https://httpbin.org/get?b=2'), 
               get('https://httpbin.org/get?c=3')]).then(values => { 
    console.log(values);
  });
});
```

```html
<button>get</button>
```

On the Network panel you can see that all three requests execute simultaneously:[image: devtools screenshot of simultaneous requests]

Comment: you can edit my answers without me having to approve an edit?! Sorcery.

Comment: Yes, when you get enough reputation on SO. Prior to this, you can suggest edits and wait for approval from multiple users in the community. If you are unhappy with an edit, you can of course change it, but the idea is that the community works together. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit :)

Comment: Glad, that helped. I just had to add the third json call after the initial two promises.push() calls.